# Git missing tags when doing fresh repo clone/checkout

Tags: git

I have a repo on machineA [edit: and another, separate repository on a server or hosting provider] which has some tags. I see these tags [on machineA] when I do `git tag -l` or look in`.git/refs/tags`:

```
$ ls .git/refs/tags
v0.0.1  v0.0.2  v0.0.3  v0.0.4
```

Now, if I go to machineB and do a clone of the repo [that is on the server or hosting provider, **not** the repo on machineA]. None of the tags are available [on machineB]. I tried  `git fetch --all --tags`. I also tried `git tag -l`. The `.git/refs/tags` is empty also. What am I doing wrong? These tags were inserted by the python-semantic-release module.

Comment: `--all` means *all remotes* and is normally useless (albeit harmless). The `--tags` option *should* get you their tags. Looking in the `.git/refs/` directory is not helpful as references are not always unpacked, but they should show up in `git tag -l` output. (I don't know why you are not seeing them.)

Comment: Thanks. I came along this link http://www.thisprogrammingthing.com/2013/git-tags-not-showing-in-github. My repo is hosted by Gitlab EE inside a corporate environment. I will try `git push --tags` to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Aha, you didn't mention that there are *three* repositories involved. You really have machine-A which has tags, machine-B which is an intermediate, and machine-C on which you're looking for the tags ... and you're doing a push from A to B, then a fetch from C to B.

Comment: Confirmed `git push --tags` fixed this problem.

Answer (score 3):

As in the comments and my update of your question with corrected facts, the problem is that you've never *sent* the tags from machineA to the server-or-hosted repository.  You need to use `git push --tags`, or an explicit `git push` of each tag, from machineA to the server, so that the *server* will have the tags, before machineB can get those tags from the server.

(Cloning on machineB *directly from* machineA would also work.)